# Bibliography output styles

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibitem

I am writing an assignment and using biblatex package to handle the bibliography. Now the output of my code is like 
[image: output with biblatex package]
while my supervisor needs me to write the reference in format like this
[image: Required bibliography format]

The difference is that the Vol #, Issue # and month-year have been written in different styles/format. I want to know is there any way that I can make these changes i.e. instead of printing 51.12 (2005), pp. 4203-4215, it prints Vol 51, no. 12, pp. 4203-4215, 2005.

Reference code is;

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}

\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{fig/}{graphs/}}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sorting=none,minnames=3]{biblatex}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

% Title Page
\title{Assignment}
\author{Salman}
\date{\today --- \currenttime}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

Compressive Sampling (CS) has been studied in \cite{1614066}. Based on the theory, a exact singal reconstruction technique is proposed in \cite{1580791}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And the bib file code is;

```
    @ARTICLE{1614066, 
    author={D. L. Donoho}, 
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Information Theory}, 
    title={Compressed sensing}, 
    volume={52}, 
    number={4}, 
    pages={1289-1306},
    month={April}, 
    year={2006}
}
@ARTICLE{1580791, 
    author={E. J. Candes and J. Romberg and T. Tao}, 
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Information Theory}, 
    title={Robust uncertainty principles: exact signal reconstruction from highly incomplete frequency information}, 
    volume={52}, 
    number={2}, 
    pages={489-509},
    month={Feb},
    year={2006}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired output from the screenshot looks very much like the IEEE style implemented by [`biblatex-ieee`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee).

I can't identify the used style with absolute certainty since the screenshot only shows entries of type `@article` and does not use additional features like DOIs or URLs, but the output for the two `@articles` in your MWE should be a match. The style definitely prints journal information as

> vol 51, no. 12, pp. 4203-4215, 2005.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{donoho, 
  author  = {D. L. Donoho},
  journal = {IEEE Transactions on Information Theory},
  title   = {Compressed sensing}, 
  volume  = {52}, 
  number  = {4}, 
  pages   = {1289-1306},
  month   = {4}, 
  year    = {2006}
}
@article{candes, 
  author  = {E. J. Candes and J. Romberg and T. Tao}, 
  journal = {IEEE Transactions on Information Theory}, 
  title   = {Robust uncertainty principles: exact signal
             reconstruction from highly incomplete frequency information}, 
  volume  = {52}, 
  number  = {2}, 
  pages   = {489-509},
  month   = {2},
  year    = {2006}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{donoho,candes,sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: D. L. Donoho, “Compressed sensing,” IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, vol. 52, no. 4, pp. 1289–1306, Apr. 2006.//E. J. Candes, J. Romberg and T. Tao, “Robust uncertainty principles: Exact signal reconstruction from highly incomplete frequency information,” IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, vol. 52, no. 2, pp. 489–509, Feb. 2006.//E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde, “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments,” Journal of Computational Chemistry, vol. 19, no. 4, pp. 377–395, 1998. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, you are right. I guess I need the reference to be output in IEEE format.

But I am getting error with the changes you suggested i.e. stype=ieee,backend=biber

The errors are;

I found no \citation commands

I found no \bibdata command

I found no \bibstyle command

I even copied/pasted your code but still got the same error messages.

Comment: @SalmanKhan You are running BibTeX while my MWE wants you to run Biber. Either tell your editor to run Biber (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) or change from `backend=biber` to `backend=bibtex`. But with BibTeX you will only be able to access a reduced set of features.